# Comparing two populations [Beginner]

Tags: standard-deviation, sample, mean

I have sampled from two separate populations, and I want to figure out which population is better.

Population 1 has an average score of 84.1 and a standard deviation of 11.8.  Population 2 has an average score of 95.8 and a standard deviation of 13.5.

Assume that all samples are independent, and the sample size is 500 for each population.

What is the best way to prove that a random sample from population 2 will result in a greater score (on average) than a random sample from population 1?

What statistic do I need? Confidence interval? Tolerance interval?

Comment: You cannot prove that conclusion, because it is false: these statistics suffice to demonstrate the possibility that a random sample of Population 2 *could have* a smaller mean score than an independent random sample of Population 1.  What you can do is to test the hypothesis that the population mean scores have the same value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the data is big enough, you can score of populations are taken,I assume scores made independently....

So, Normal Assumption is the Best for this situation

$H_0:\bar{P_1}=\bar{P_2}$

$H_1:\bar{P_2}\not=\bar{P_1}$

if $H_0$ is true, then $\bar{P_2}-\bar{P_1} \sim N(0,\frac{\sigma_{P_1}^2}{500}+\frac{\sigma_{P_2}^2}{500}) $

You can get $Z=\Bigg(\frac{(\bar{P_2}-\bar{P_1})-0}{\sqrt{\frac{\sigma_{P_1}^2}{500}+\frac{\sigma_{P_2}^2}{500}}}\Bigg)$

Now, you can check it out whether the difference is very high from the "Standard Normal Tables" at any error level,say, 5%(2.5%&97.5%)

Note:- suppose error-level taken as 5%(rejection criterion will be below -1.96 and above 1.96)....

So if Z is above 1.96, $P_2$ will be better.
& if Z is below -1.96 $P_1$ will be better.
Otherwise $H_0$ holds

Comment: I'm not sure if I fully understand.  Is this a one-tailed test? Can you do an example please?

Comment: A one-tailed test is inappropriate for this question. When it is not known *a priori* which population might have the greater mean, a two-tailed test is needed.  The best clue to interpretation is the key phrase, "figure out which population is better."

Comment: Ohh yes! Pardon, previously I misread! Now cleared :)

Answer (score 0):

If m1 and m2 are means, s1 and s2 are standard deviations and n1 and n2 are sample sizes, you can use following equations (code in R):

```
mean_diff = m1-m2
se <- sqrt( (s1^2/n1) + (s2^2/n2) )
df <- ( (s1^2/n1 + s2^2/n2)^2 )/( (s1^2/n1)^2/(n1-1) + (s2^2/n2)^2/(n2-1) )
t <- (m1-m2)/se 
P_value = 2*pt(-abs(t),df)
```

'pt' is a function in R to get P values. See ?pt for help.

Comment: Please express your formulas in math or English (or both).  Relying on a computing language not only can be inaccurate, it also limits your audience unnecessarily.